# how to expose metrics from prometheus

Tags: prometheus, datadog

I am currently using prometheus to view metrics sourced from instaclustr and I wish to expose these metrics in such a way that they can be picked up by datadog. I can see the metrics are being successfully sent from instaclustr to prometheus and the relevant endpoints are showing under targets in the prometheus UI.

I am adding the annotations to the helm chart I am using to deploy prometheus in accordance with https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/prometheus/?tab=kubernetesadv2 - if I do this datadog should pick up the metrics
However, for the openmetrics_endpoint I have no idea how to expose the metrics I have initially sourced from instaclustr (and thus I don't have a value to put for the openmetrics_endpoint) - does anyone know how to do this? The urls I can see under targets seem to be from instaclustr and not from prometheus, and when I tried using those urls datadog doens't pick up the metrics.

To be clear, I'm not asking how to expose metrics from other applications so that they can be picked up by prometheus - what I'm after is how to expose custom metrics FROM prometheus so that datadog can detect them.

Comment: I have no real clue what this question is about, but I have a hunch that prometheus' [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) endpoint `/federate` is what you are looking for.